# Is there any value to use a timeout on CDN request to help w proxy issues?

Tags: javascript, html, performance, cdn

My work is behind a pretty ridiculous proxy, and I've noticed that occasionally when testing a page that's loading a JS library through CDN, it just hangs while loading the CDN file.

I include libraries through CDNs with the HTML5 boilerplate trick:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="_/js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js">\x3C/script>')</script>
```

But even with the fallback it still sometimes hangs on the external http request. I presume eventually it connects or times out and will end up loading, but while it's hanging there nothing happens.

This has been testing local files, so I'm not sure if it would ever be an issue if both pages are on the WWW, but I know various pages take particularly longtime to load behind our proxy, and I know that a lot of computers at large corporations are decently likely to behind something similar.

I am considering whether it would be valuable to try and figure out some kind of timeout, where if the CDN hasn't responded within a very short amount of time it just loads the local file.. instead of waiting for a full on time-out (which is my interpretation of what it does now, but I could be wrong)

I am not super knowledgeable about networking and requests and such, so I'm not sure if this would be useful to do, or if I'm likely misidentifying the problem (the hanging issues are pretty rare, too, so I'm not sure how to test reliably in my rather limited environment here)

Comment: Why don't you just stop using the CDN all together? Using it is only good if it saves load time.

Comment: closely related - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2021157/any-way-to-gracefully-enforce-a-timeout-limit-when-loading-a-slow-external-file

Comment: @Bryan it's faster in the majority of situations, especially with caching.

Comment: I usually use a local copy in adevelopment environment, then switch to a CDN in production/staging. If our internet goes down at work, I still need access to my JavaScript frameworks. Not sure if you're able to do this as well.