# Dealing with failures or slowness of loading resources from CDN.

Tags: javascript, cdn, fallback

I'm using a CDN (maxcdn.com) for js, css and images on a web site. I've noticed that from some ISP's, those resources either completely fail to load or load very slowly. However, local static serving from my server always works fine. Therefore, I want to be able to detect such resource loading failures and respond to them by falling back to local serving.

I've found here several solutions for detecting js and css loading failures. The most common is to check for some js var and some cssRules from css using embedded js (positioned just before the , after the script and link tags). However, this doesn't allow to:

1. detect slow loading (fallback should start as soon as slowness is detected…)
2. detect load failures for images referenced from css.

**Is there any simple, elegant way to detect resources loading failures/slowness and quickly fall back to local serving?**

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=cdn+fallback

Comment: @Andreas I did search for similar questions, and none of the found solutions fit: they can't detect _slow_ loading of resources, only a complete failure (which can occur after long-time pending)

Comment: And [this topic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2021157/any-way-to-gracefully-enforce-a-timeout-limit-when-loading-a-slow-external-file) would also be unhelpful?

Comment: @raina77ow this may be helpful for js and css files, but not for images. But anyway thank you!

Comment: CDN is supposed to be faster, but people are getting it wrong, CDN servers have finally become shared hosting nightmare with overselling. Serving content locally is always better, because in today's network, difference of few millisecond does not make difference to user when resource will be loaded once and cached. In both cases, CDN up your server down, CDN down your server up, your user fail to get the website running. CDN should be used for video and bigger resources, not for JavaScript and images.

Answer (score 2):

As noted here https://stackoverflow.com/a/2021325/745190 there's no way to disable a script after starting to load it.

You could try loading a very small (.1kb) script initially from the cdn. Test that script after a very small space of time, if it downloads use javascript to append the other script tags to your page, if it doesn't it's a small file unnecessarily downloaded.

Sadly this method has two major drawbacks. The first is that there's an extra query to the cdn, the second is that failure to load the small script altogether might lead your browser wheel to keep spinning.

the test if you're unsure is something like this:

```
/* tiny-file.js */
var window.speedTest = true;
```

and

```
/* The test */
setTimeout(function(){
    if (window.speedTest !== true) {
        //append local javascript
    }
    else {
        //append cdn javascript
    }
}, 50);
```

Comment: how does this answer the question on detecting failed loads of images?

Comment: I'm assuming that the issue is the connection to the cdn rather than the download speed of any single piece of content. You need to check what the relative speed is, you can append the images with javascript as easily as script tags.

Comment: There is no way to check if it is just being slow or failing. This is quite a good solution though, although I would give it more than 50ms!

Comment: and what if I add this tiny script as "async"? (for browsers that support this) Will it prevent browser from being locked until either the request fails completely or the script is loaded?

Comment: You could try. You might not want the page to load before your images are ready, or if you use this method to append style-sheets, before your page can be styled. Depending on the load you expect on your page you can make a judgement call on this. If you expect a lot of hits allow longer for the cdn to load, if you want pages to individually load rapidly go for a lower value, but expect to serve more content straight from your server.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that your issue will mostly occur with some ISPs.

If your main goal is to achieve performance while keeping the CDN as the main solution, I can see tow options. The first, you try to identify failing ISPs but it might be pretty long and expensive.
Another option is to "learn". Try to load a trivial JS setting a variable from the CDN. If it fails, you can assume there is a problem. Set a cookie and use it on the next page load to automatically load everything from your main server.

Comment: how would you deal with a situation in which mostly images fail to load while the js var test appears to pass successfully?

Comment: I would do the opposite: set a variable *before* loading a set of known images and then decreasing it in a "load" event. A timeout could then be used to read the variable and decide what to do.

Comment: @jtlebi and how would you attach a load event to an image referenced from css (as background for some element)?

Comment: No idea how to attach it a load event. But you can rely on the fact that images are loaded only once per page load. Reference the same image from your HTML in a far away but "visible" div and attach the event to it.